When using pocketbase with svelte, pocketbase returns a 'fetch failed' error unless an instance of pocketbase is running using ./pocketbase serve'
So I have a simple svelte app in which I want to perform CRUD operations using pocketbase. I have setup a collection "user" in pocketbase which has a table of fields name and age. I tried to perform a create operation using svelte actions which accepts a form data (containing the name and age) and creates a new user in the collection.
import PocketBase from 'pocketbase'
import { SECRET_EMAIL, SECRET_PASS } from '$env/static/private'

export const actions = {
    create: async({request}) => {
        const pb = new PocketBase("http://127.0.0.1:8090");
        await pb.admins.authWithPassword(SECRET_EMAIL, SECRET_PASS);

        const form = await request.formData();
        const name = form.get("name");
        const age = form.get("age");

        const newRecord = {
            name,
            age,
        }

        const record = await pb.collection("users").create(newRecord);
    }
}

But whenever I ran the dev server and tried to submit the form it would return the following error:
ClientResponseError 0: Something went wrong while processing your request.
    at file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/VSC%20temp/svelte/pb/app/node_modules/pocketbase/dist/pocketbase.es.mjs:1:32313
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async AdminService.authWithPassword (file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/VSC%20temp/svelte/pb/app/node_modules/pocketbase/dist/pocketbase.es.mjs:1:10785)
    at async create (eval at instantiateModule (file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/VSC%20temp/svelte/pb/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:55068:28), <anonymous>:11:9)
    at async Module.handle_action_request (eval at instantiateModule (file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/VSC%20temp/svelte/pb/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:55068:28), <anonymous>:131:18)
    at async Module.render_page (eval at instantiateModule (file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/VSC%20temp/svelte/pb/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:55068:28), <anonymous>:70:20)
    at async resolve (eval at instantiateModule (file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/VSC%20temp/svelte/pb/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:55068:28), <anonymous>:457:18)
    at async Module.respond (eval at instantiateModule (file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/VSC%20temp/svelte/pb/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:55068:28), <anonymous>:330:20)
    at async file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/VSC%20temp/svelte/pb/app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:524:22 {      
  url: '',
  status: 0,
  response: {},
  isAbort: false,
  originalError: TypeError: fetch failed
      at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12442:11
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async AdminService.authWithPassword (file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/VSC%20temp/svelte/pb/app/node_modules/pocketbase/dist/pocketbase.es.mjs:1:10785)
      at async create (eval at instantiateModule (file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/VSC%20temp/svelte/pb/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:55068:28), <anonymous>:11:9)
      at async Module.handle_action_request (eval at instantiateModule (file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/VSC%20temp/svelte/pb/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:55068:28), <anonymous>:131:18)
      at async Module.render_page (eval at instantiateModule (file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/VSC%20temp/svelte/pb/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:55068:28), <anonymous>:70:20)
      at async resolve (eval at instantiateModule (file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/VSC%20temp/svelte/pb/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:55068:28), <anonymous>:457:18)
      at async Module.respond (eval at instantiateModule (file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/VSC%20temp/svelte/pb/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:55068:28), <anonymous>:330:20)
      at async file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/VSC%20temp/svelte/pb/app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:524:22 {    
    cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8090
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16)
        at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
      errno: -4078,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 8090
    }
  }
}

But the issue is resolved and I am able to perform the create operation successfully when I start the pocketbase server manually using ./pocketbase serve in a new terminal.

My question is am I supposed to run an instance of pocketbase manually like this or am I doing something wrong? My assumption is that the line const pb = new Pocketbase("http://127.0.0.1:8090"); starts the pocketbase server without my doing so manually.
And if I am supposed to do this then could you please also tell me what other steps I should take when building the app to deploy it? Thanks a lot!

I've never heard of Pocketbase before, but in general, *My assumption is that the line const pb = new Pocketbase("http://127.0.0.1:8090"); starts the pocketbase server without my doing so manually.` sounds very strange to me. Most likely, that line of code simple tells your web browser how to connect to the Pocketbase server, and most likely you should start the Pocketbase server manually.

Alright thanks so much. I thought it would be something like this.

This is expected. The line
const pb = new Pocketbase("http://127.0.0.1:8090");

is simply connecting an instance of a Pocketbase to a pocketbase server hosted elsewhere, in this case at 127.0.0.1:8090
